# Fine uploader Async task works in Chrome but not in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, fine-uploader, fileapi

I use [Fineuploader Promise](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/async-tasks-and-promises.html) to run md5 check in submit callback to prevent the files already exist upload again,it works in chrome but not in IE11. is't a IE bug or i do it wrong?how can I fix it? Thanks a lot.
here is the script:

```
 $("#uploader").fineUploader({
    request: {
        endpoint: 'home/upload'
    },
    multiple: true,
    autoUpload: false,
    debug: true,
    chuncking: {
        enabled:true
    },
    editFilename: {                                            
        enable: true
    },
    validation: {
        sizeLimit: 1073741824
    }
}).on({                                                      
    "complete": function (event, id, fileName, responseJSON) { 
        if (responseJSON.success) {
            alert("upload success");
        }
    },
    "validate": function (event,data) {

    },
    "submit": function (event,id, fileName) {             

        var promise = new qq.Promise();
        var file = $(this).fineUploader('getFile', id);
        var freader = new FileReader();
        validateMD5(file, freader,promise);
        return promise;
    },

    "error": function (event, id, fileName, reason) {
        alert(reason);
    }
});



$("#uploadButton").click(function () {
    $('#uploader').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
});
function validateMD5(file, reader,promise) {

    var blobSlice = File.prototype.mozSlice || File.prototype.webkitSlice || File.prototype.slice;
    var spark = new SparkMD5();
    var chunkSize = 2097152;
    var chunks = Math.ceil(file.size / chunkSize);
    var currentChunk = 0;
    var start1 = 0;
    var end1 = chunkSize >= file.size ? file.size : chunkSize;
    reader.readAsBinaryString(blobSlice.call(file, start1, end1));
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        spark.appendBinary(e.target.result);
        currentChunk++;
        if (currentChunk < chunks) {
            var start = currentChunk * chunkSize;
            var end = start + chunkSize >= file.size ? file.size : start + chunkSize;
            reader.readAsBinaryString(blobSlice.call(file, start, end));
        } else {
            var md5 = spark.end();
            var r = checkMd5Onserver(md5);
            if (r == true) {
                promise.success();
            } else {
                promise.failure();
            }
        }

    };
}

function checkMd5Onserver(md5) {
    return false;//just for test
}
```

Comment: You just asked this question a few hours ago.  It received a good answer and useful comments.  What happened to it?

Comment: I was put some wrong code in that question,@jfriend00 point it out,i shouldn't edit my question just change it different.@jfriend00 demand me delete that question and start a new one..and i still don't know why it worked in chrome but not work ie?

Comment: I just find out that this is because the IE11 is no longer support FileReader.readAsBinaryString()

Comment: Hmm, it looks like that method was removed from the spec.  I wasn't aware of that myself.  Please post your finding as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my code I read file using FileReader.readAsBinaryString() method,it's no longer support by IE11. more details in [FileReader.readAsBinaryString function-- doesnt work on IE11](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/808637/-ie-11-error-filereader-readasbinarystring-function-doesnt-work-on-ie11) and http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader